# Make Pentaho report for Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

Currently I'm trying to install [Pentaho Reports for OpenERP](https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP/blob/master/java_server/build.xml). I have installed Pentaho Reports on Windows based laptops and they are working fine. Currently I'm trying on Ubuntu 11.04 and it gives me this error:

> error build.xml: 18: failed to create task or type.

Below are the steps I performed:

1. Installed `java-6-openjdk` from the repository

   ```
   apt-get install java-6-openjdk
   ```
2. Then I set installed Java JDK into java_home environment

   ```
   nano /etc/environment
   ```

   Added environment with this new line:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
   ```
3. I then installed Apache ant from the repository

   ```
   apt-get install ant
   ```
4. Followed by setting the environment

   ```
   nano /etc/environment
   ```

   Added environment with this new line:

   ```
   ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
   ```
5. Tried to check installation with command `ant`... and I get messages like this:

   ```
   Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
   Build failed
   ```
6. Then downloaded Java server from [Pentaho Reports for OpenERP](https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP/blob/master/java_server/build.xml) and then copied to Ubuntu share folder. And then from command line, I went to extracted path which is the share folder. I mentioned and executed command `ant war` and I got this error message:

   ```
   BUILD FAILED
   /share/java_server/build.xml: 18: problem: failed to create task or
   type antlibrg:apacge.ivy.ant: retrieve
   cause: The name is undefined.
   Action: Check the spelling.
   Action: Check that any custom taks/types have been declared
   Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef>declarations have taken place.
   No types or taks have been defined in this namespace yet
   This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
   Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
      - /usr/share/ant/lib
      -/root/.ant/lib
      - A directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

   Total time: 0 seconds
   ```

Is there any compatibility issue? Or am I missing out some steps?

Comment: You are updating your environment but your current session is unaware of those changes, thus using the old settings. Either use the `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk` and `export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant` or log out and log back in.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps (they worked for me):

- Update openjdk-6-jdk
- In /etc/environment add:

  ```
  JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
  JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre"
  ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant/bin"
  PATH = ".....:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$ANT_HOME:/usr/share/ant/lib"
  ```
- Restart your system
- In java_server input the command `ant war`. You should get this message:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
  Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher. Program will exit.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact the build system cannot find ivy libraries. You have to install ivy first:

```
apt-get install ivy
```

If still complaining with the same error, run the ant job using:

```
ant -lib /usr/share/java/ war
```

where /usr/share/java/ is a path, where ivy installs the .jar files.

BTW: I don't know what exactly did you clone from git, but on the link you sent is the ivy resource defined on the line 27, not 18, like you say.